# Following correct practise when building view models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have run into a caveat with regards to my approach to ASP.NET MVC and viewmodels. Essentially what I do is build a viewmodel in controller/action which merges models together and then passes it to the view.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MyAction1()
    {
     List<StaffModel> staffList = new List<StaffModel>();
     var qryStaff = context.Staff.Select(c => new { c.ID, c.name});
      foreach (var item in qryStaff )
        {
            StaffModel myStaffViewModel = new StaffModel
            {   
                ID = item.ID, Name = item.Name
            };
            staffList.Add(myStaffViewModel );
        }
```

So I do the above process and also do it with employees, exactly the same and then put it into employeeList. I then create my viewModel as the view.

```
           EmployeeStaffViewModel viewModel = new EmployeeStaffViewModel 
        {                
            Staff = staffList,
            Employee = employeeList
        };
```

I then return the view. I have used employee & staff as an example. I actually have more models I add to the viewModel EmployeeStaffViewModel . It's getting quite big all within the controller action. Should I be creating a ViewModel as a class and then instantiating it in my controller so all the linq and foreach goes in the Model. Therefore I can use it in another controller action.

Thank you for any advice. Will be greatly received.

Comment: yes, you should make a separate class for your view model, if you are trying to stick to the separation of concerns that is a selling point of MVC

Comment: So all of my LINQ and foreach should be in my EmployeeStaffViewModel not in the controller/action??? Is this the correct approach? I have just been using model classes solely as a Data access layer and declaring enumerables.

Comment: It's kind of a matter of opinion.  Obviously you can write logic into your controllers.  For me personally if I only have to present say a title a long with a model that comes straight from a database table, then I put those couple of lines in the controller.  However, if you have a view that is displaying data from multiple tables, along with a title and a bunch of other things, then a view model is the way to go.  Also the view models help with re-usability, in that you can have the same view model called from multiple actions.

Comment: In my current project I've added a 'View Model' folder and it currently contains 7 view model classes.

Comment: That's what I was hoping because I thought I was going wrong with this massive controller/action full of LINQ and static method calls. Thank you for your sound advice I will do the View Model folder. I'm trying to work out a way to give you credit for the comment.

Comment: you dont want to put a ton of logic in your view model classes.. DbContext queries make more sense in the controller than in the ViewModel..  Mapping your Entity properties to your Model properties and vise versa can be done in your view model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have 3 classes in your `~/Models` folder

**StaffModel.cs**

```
public class StaffModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static Func<Staff, StaffModel> Project = item => new StaffModel
    { 
        ID = item.ID,
        Name = item.Name
    };
}
```

**EmployeeModel.cs**

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static Func<Employee, EmployeeModel> Project = item => new EmployeeModel
    {
        ID = item.ID,
        Name = item.Name
    };
}
```

**EmployeeStaffViewModel.cs**

```
public class EmployeeStaffViewModel
{
    public EmployeeStaffViewModel()
    {
        Staff = new List<StaffModel>();
        Employee = new List<EmployeeModel>();
    }
    public List<StaffModel> Staff { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeModel> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

The StaffModel and EmployeeModel both have a static Func<> that will map your db entity to your models.  These Funcs can be used in your linq queries and expressions which you'll see below.

Your controller action is where you will retrieve your entities from your context.  You can simplify your code to not have as many lines as you do.

**MyController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction1()
{
    var model = new EmployeeStaffViewModel();
    model.Staff = context.Staff.Select(StaffModel.Project);  //Select Staff to StaffModel List
    model.Employee = context.Employee.Select(EmployeeModel.Project); //Select Employee to EmployeeModel List
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: This is formidable info you have provided me with. Thank you.